# How to get extension of file from URI?

Tags: java, android

I am selecting a file from the galley and then in onActivityResult, I am getting the Uri. Now
I want to get the extension of the file from Uri. I tried many ways but none of them worked. Please help.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        
         Uri uri = data.getData();

}
```

Comment: There may not *be* a file extension. Use `ContentResolver` and `getType()` to get the MIME type of the image. If you still need a file extension, use `MimeTypeMap` to get a common file extension based on the MIME type.

Comment: What do you want the "extension" for? It's likely that it doesn't actually _do_ what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String extension =  data.getPath().substring(data.getPath().lastIndexOf("."))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the content resolver to query the uri for .DISPLAY_NAME.

The name comes with extension.